# How to make radio buttons required and have a possible default value

Tags: forms

I have a set of radio buttons. I first check the database to see if one of the options has already been set for the user and if so add it to `$attending`. If none have been set I don't want a default value. I thought I could achieve this by setting `default_value` to `false`. The problem I have is that when setting `default_value` to `false` and I submit the form without selecting an `attending` option, Drupal does not give me an error saying I didn't select an option for that radio group. How do I set a default value to nothing so that Drupal gives an error when I try to submit without selecting an option?

```
$form['attending'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => t('Will you be attending?'),
  '#options' => array(
    '1'   => t('Yes'),
    '0' => t('No'),
  ),
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#default_value' => isset($attending) ? $attending : false,
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why this happens; maybe `FALSE` is being cast to an integer in the validation, being evaluated as `0`, and becoming an acceptable selection (your value for "No" being `0`).

Fortunately you can use `NULL` instead:

```
'#default_value' => isset($attending) ? $attending : NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I don't know why I didn't try `NULL` before.